# how to move a movie clip from a ref movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to make a movieClip which has a reference of another movie clip move.
 But when i do it it stays still. 
 Here is an example code i am trying to do

```
 var movieClip1 = new movieClip();
 var movieClip2 = new movieClip();

movieClip1.ref = movieClip2;
movieClip1.x = 0;
movieClip2.x = 0;
addChild(movieClip1);
addChild(movieClip2);

while(movieClip1.x !=300){
movieClip1.x +=1;
// i want to make the reference of the clip move as well
movieClip1.ref.x = movieClip1.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you wanting it to move? Progressively, 1 unit at a time? If so Don't use a while loop or it will simply jump straight to 300 (x position).

Instead use some sort of update loop like an enter frame listener:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
function Update(e:Event):void
{
    mc1.x++;
    mc1.ref.x = mc1.x;
}
```

Comment: i have put it in the enter frame but the mc1.ref.x still wont move.

Comment: @user62927, I tested the your code using the suggestion of Sim and this is working.

Comment: Is the code you posted the exact code you're using, user62927? If so, do you have an actual movieclip assigned to the movieClip class you're referencing in your code?